# Axios + VueJs3: Display the Results using Async Export

Tags: typescript, axios, promise, vuejs3

I am using vue.js3 with vite and axios.

i defined a TS file with this function:

```
export async function findAllCompanies() {
    try {
        const {data, status} = await axios.get<CompanyPojoResponse>(
            'http://localhost:9050/api/v1/company/all',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5QYXNz',
                },
            },
        );

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

        // ?? "response status is: 200"
        console.log('response status is: ', status);

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            console.log('error message: ', error.message);
            console.log('error message: ', error);
            return error.message;
        } else {
            console.log('unexpected error: ', error);
            return 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
    }
}
```

then, i am trying to display it in a vue-file:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import type {CompanyPojo} from "@/rest/restapi-companies";
import {findAllCompanies} from "@/rest/restapi-companies";

let companyResult = findAllCompanies()
console.log(companyResult)

</script>

<template>

  <div class="top-nav">
    <nav>
      <RouterLink to="/new-company">New Company</RouterLink>
      <!-- view product list -->
      <!-- create new product -->
    </nav>
  </div>

  <table id="companyTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>JUST EVERYTHING....</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr v-for="company in companyResult">
      <td>{{ company }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</template>
```

I see results within the logs, but not at the page (added company just for testing)
trying to access fields:
{{ company.name }}
{{ company.additionalName }}

is just resulting in an error, that CompanyPojoResponse does not have those fields.

which i really don't understand, since:

```
export type CompanyPojoResponse = {
    data: CompanyPojo[];
};
```

I thought i am looping over the data at this point and then i loop therefor over CompanyPojo-Objects...

Comment: Please close this question as duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75678020/vue-js3-and-axios-async-table-not-updated

Answer (score 1):

Your `findAllCompanies()` is an async function, you are not waiting for the promise to be resolved.

You can do something like this:

```js
const companyResult = ref([]) // Initialize this as an empty array

onMounted(async () => {
  companyResult.value = await findAllCompanies()
})
```

Comment: it says:

TS2322: Type 'string | CompanyPojoResponse' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.

Comment: i tried this by now:

    const companyResultRef = ref([]) // Initialize this as an empty array

onMounted(async () => {
  await findAllCompanies().then((response) => {companyResult2.value = response.data})
})

and:

    <tr v-for="company in companyResult2">
      <td>{{ company.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ company.additionalName }}</td>
      <td>{{ company.legalForm }}</td>
    </tr>

but still.. no display of results (console shows results)