# Vue.js3 and axios async - table not updated?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

regarding my research it seem that i've done every thing right. At least, i can't see the problem why my table is not updated.

first, i create a new company, then i got to overview, but nothing is shown. Within my logs I'm seeing all those created companies, but none will render.

In the console in the webbrowser i am seeing data logged from restapi-companies.

On fetching those companies, nothing goes wrong.

Is there any event i need to call for action, or what's the problem here?

here is my full dev-code:

1. restapi-companies.ts:

```js
export type CompanyPojo = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  legalForm: string;
  additionalName: string;
};

export type CompanyPojoResponse = {
  data: CompanyPojo[];
};

import axios from "axios";

export async function findAllCompanies() {
  try {
    const { data, status } = await axios.get<CompanyPojoResponse>(
      "http://localhost:9050/api/v1/company/all",
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5QYXNz",
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

    // ?? "response status is: 200"
    console.log("response status is: ", status);

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
      console.log("error message: ", error.message);
      console.log("error message: ", error);
    } else {
      console.log("unexpected error: ", error);
    }
  }

  return <CompanyPojoResponse>{};
}
```

2. Vue-Template

```js
<script>
import { findAllCompanies } from "@/rest/restapi-companies"
import { ref } from "vue"

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      companies: ref([])
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    findAllCompanies().then((response) => {
      this.companies = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="top-nav">
    <nav>
      <RouterLink to="/new-company">New Company</RouterLink>
      <!-- view product list -->
      <!-- create new product -->
    </nav>
  </div>

  <table id="companyTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Additional Name</th>
        <th>Legal Form</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="company in companies">
        <td>{{ company.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ company.additionalName }}</td>
        <td>{{ company.legalForm }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're unwrapping `data` from response twice: once inside `findAllCompanies` (destructuring `data`) and once in `mounted()` (`response.data`).

```
  // ...
  mounted() {
    findAllCompanies().then((data) => {
      this.companies = data
    })
  }
```

...should fix it.

---

Side note: `data` is already reactive, no need to place anything reactive inside it (so `ref([])` is unnecessary.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({ companies: [] }),
  //...
}
```

...will do.

---

Since you're using Vue3 and Typescript, you should probably write your component as:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { findAllCompanies, CompanyPojo } from "@/rest/restapi-companies"
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue"

const companies = ref<CompanyPojo[]>([])
onMounted(async () => {
  companies.value = await findAllCompanies()
})
</script>
```

And you might want to return an empty array (not an empty object) from the error branch.

Comment: using the setup lang="ts" approach throws me an error:

TS2322: Type 'CompanyPojoResponse | never[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.

"And you might want to return an empty array (not an empty object) from the error branch": good idea, changed it now.

Comment: on the first approach i get an empty array, there's also now log output after the fetch now.

Comment: changed it. i am writing with results of the query with  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)); - those entries i am seeing withing the dev-console of my browser.

Comment: please add this code-fences in your code at your answer, because at your answer it looks like mounted is missing! but its not. i'll remove my answer. please format yours. i've accepted your answer. thanks.

Comment: The entire component is missing. Because I only ***focused*** on the bit that was ***wrong***, to make sure you you did not miss the important bit!
Also notice I updated the TS version of your component. Should work now